# Example of Quantum Fourier Computation for three qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, fourier-transform, quantum-computer

I am currently going through Nielsen's QC bible and having still some foundational / conceptual problems with the matter.

[image: Nielsen Quantum Computing]

I have tried to retrieve this $8 {\times} 8$ matrix describing the QFT of 3 qubits via Kronecker product in various attempts.

Hadamard transform can be decomposed into $H \otimes 1 \otimes 1$, and the others are fundamentally kronecker products of the 4x4 matrices of S resp. T with the 2x2 identity.

Whats wrong with my approach?

Comment: You might try asking this at [SE.QuantumComputing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine. One thing that might be tripping you up is to make sure that the $T$ is operating on the first and third tensor factors. It is easier when the tensor factors are right next to each other so you can write $T$ operating on $2$ and $3$ as `KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2],T]` in Mathematica. So to handle $1$ and $3$ you would do

```
KroneckerProduct[Swap,IdentityMatrix[2]]
  .KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2],T]
  .KroneckerProduct[Swap,IdentityMatrix[2]]
```

Here you are giving the explicit $4{\times}4$ matrices for `Swap` and `T`. Similarly make sure to do `KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2],H,IdentityMatrix[2]]` for the second `H`.

Keep track of indices when doing the Kronecker products and don't do a matrix bigger than $3 {\times} 3$ by hand.